# How is the sun's equatorial circumference measured?

Tags: astronomy, sun

How is the sun's equatorial circumference measured by scientists?

Comment: Suggestion to the question formulation (v1): Replace the word _calculated_ with the word _measured._

Comment: Of interest: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29363/

Answer (score 9):

It is quite simple to get a reasonable measure of the sun's diameter, using a pinhole, a screen and the [formula for experiment 2 on this At Home Astronomy article: "Finding the size of the sun and moon"](http://cse.ssl.berkeley.edu/AtHomeAstronomy/activity_03.html).

From the 'At Home Astronomy' article, the sun's diameter can be calculated as:

$$\frac{\text{Diameter of the sun's image}}{\text{Distance from the pinhole to the paper}}\times\text{Earth-sun distance} = \text{Diameter of the sun}$$

Edited to add:

The first recorded attempts to determine the distances and sizes of the Earth and Moon were performed by [Aristarchus (310 - 230 B.C.)](http://www.astro.cornell.edu/academics/courses/astro201/aristarchus.htm), these were not very accurate (this information is also in the first link I gave originally).  Once the distance was known (or estimated), a measure for the size could be determined.

His method was to determine the angle to the sun when the moon was half full, hence at a right angle to the observer (a potential source of error) and measure the angle to the sun (as in the diagram below)

[image: Aristarchus' observational geometry]

([Source](http://www.astro.cornell.edu/academics/courses/astro201/aristarchus.htm))

I hope this clears up the inadequacies of my original post.

Comment: Thanks! But how did they get that formula??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove the formula they use is a derivation of relative size ratios - a bit more explanation of the maths involved is here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model

Comment: @DamienIgoe While links to more info are good, we discourage link-only answers, since they lose all value when the link inevitably dies. It would help if you provided a brief summary of the technique.

Comment: Okay, added a relevant image.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question because we don't know the object distance.  This equation correlates size and distance, and this leaves us needing one more equation.

Comment: The object, being he sun, is at a known distance.  Either the average distance or a quick search for the actual distance would work - as stated in the link above the image.

Comment: Clarified a bit more

Comment: Damien, at some historical point in time neither the size of the sun nor the radius of Earth's orbit were known, but it's angular size was (from exactly this kind of pinhole camera setup). It is very typical of physicists to consider the two measurements as equivalent to one another, and you have assumed this *single* problem to have been solved already which @AlanSE didn't find to be very interesting. And frankly neither do I. So, while this is strictly correct, it is enormously unsatisfying.

Comment: Then by all means delete it if you're not happy with it. I was just trying to help.

Comment: No one is going to delete your question on you (and indeed no one has even downvoted it), I just suspected you didn't understand Alan's objection because it was rather minimally stated.

Comment: This is very good.  To add: I was thinking to myself that the rotation of the Earth could be used to find the distance to the moon.  One could measure the angular position of the moon's center, wait 12 hours and measure it again.  With a proper correction for the motion of the moon, you can establish a similar triangle with the Earth's radius and distance to the moon as the legs.  That will give you the distance to the moon.  That's enough info to get the sun's diameter.

Answer (score -5):

It should be simply as below:
$C = \pi d$

Comment: Great, now what is $d$?

Comment: d = diameter, can be determined using the 'At home astronomy article' in my reply.

Comment: The sun area is assumed circle! and cicumference of a circle is school math and $\pi d$. However glad to help $d$ is the *diameter*.